# Regex for HTML name input validation is not working

Tags: html, regex, validation

I want to use this pattern `/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ+\.+\- ]+$/i` to validate names in `<input>` fields. But in the HTML validation this does not work. I used pristine.js before and in there it worked without any problem.

I also created a JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3et69oz8/:

```html
<form>
  <input id="first name" name="first_name" required
  pattern="/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ+\.+\- ]+$/i">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @YoKoGFX, the pattern is already treated as Unicode in the input tag and you have accounted for \i with the a-zA-Z, so just remove the / form the start and /i from the end, and you should be good. ie you should have, `"^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ+\.+\- ]+$"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to use a *string* regex pattern, not a regex literal in the HTML `pattern` attribute, and you do not have to use the case insensitive modifier as the `a-zA-Z` and `À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ` ranges include both lower- and uppercase letters.

Next, you are using `^` and `$` anchors, but the HTML `pattern` attribute anchors the match by default, it compiles the pattern with `^(?:` in front and `)$` at the end of the given pattern string. So, they are redundant here. **Same as one of the `+`, or both**, it is not clear if you want to allow the `+` symbol or not in the user input. If you do, just keep one occurrence.

Moreover, you do not need to escape the `.` inside square brackets, and `-` can be moved to the end of the character class so that you do not have to escape it.

So, you can use

```html
<form>
  <input id="first name" name="first_name" required pattern="[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ.+ -]+">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

*Details*:

- `^(?:` (added implicitly) - start of string and start of the non-capturing group
- `[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ.+ -]+` - one of the chars specified in the character set/ranges. **Note** the `+`, remove if users are not allowed to input it.
- `)$` (added implicitly) - end of the group and string.